# How to sync (system) folders remotely on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sync

I have about 80 remote computers that need weekly (identical) updating. What I am trying to do is setup a master computer where slave computers will sync/mirror specific files/folders.

For example: If I change a c:\folder and all of its contents on master. I would like slave to automatically update to mirror that change. The issue is that these computers are not geographically close to each other so it has to happen over the internet.

edit: This connection should only be one way. I don't want slave computers to have the ability to change the master.

Comment: Windows simply wasn't designed to be managed this way.  Don't try to sync windows at the filesystem level  You will seriously trash things.  Instead using something like puppet/gpo/(your favorite windows configuration management system)/etc to perform the same change to every system.

Comment: Meant to be designed or not this is the dilemma I am faced with. I have two folders (one that sits at root) that need weekly changes and I cannot rely on every person to update properly. I'm looking for the easiest way one person can manage this task.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) in a script, and the [Task scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/schedule-a-task) to sync a folder from our main server to all the branches nightly.

Works like a charm.

We used PowerShell to make the script.  It has a static array of computers/IPs to sync to, which it iterates through and launches the Robocopy copies in individual processes/threads, so they all run at once.

Robocopy is set to mirror (`/MIR`), so that it ensures the target computers exactly match the source.

You may not want to launch 80 of them all at once, but doing it in groups of 5-10 shouldn't be too difficult to pull off.

Comment: What about synchronising installed applications? Would SCCM be the only solution?

Comment: @RandolphWest good question. My POV on this was just for basically data folders, but I would think that if the program was installed ahead of time and you were just updating the folder (and maybe sync the registry entries for it as well, some other way) you should be good.  That's what we're syncing (our main LOB app to all branch servers), and the clients themselves have their registry parts kept up-to-date via logon scripting, so things keep working as expected. :)

Answer (score -1):

the fastest way to sync files between servers is to use P2P protocols. [Bittorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync/downloads) will be a good choice for you.

Comment: This is actually a really cool program. The problem is that it creates a two-way link and I don't want anyone to be able to make changes to the master computer.

Comment: @user275667 I haven't tried it myself yet but BTSync **does** have a **read only** option to share a folder. So it doesn't always have to be a two-way link.